# Slow login on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, login

The login time period (the period of time between the password is entered and the dock is shown on the desktop) is extremely slow (~3 minutes). After the system is up it behaves normally.

How can I trace what login item(s) may slow the login process down?

Gil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the time when you enter your password to login.

Once logged in, run the **Console** application from `/Applications/Utilities` and look at the **All messages** log. Look back to the time you entered your password and what messages appear between then and now.

[image]

Anything seem suspicious? Any entries citing errors connecting to a network share, internet resource, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Login Items

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on Users and Groups
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Remove any entries in there that you don't recognize or don't need

Comment: Do this **very** carefully.

Answer (score 0):

What are your system specs? Are there multiple users that login into this machine regularly or attached to network?

Else, you could try backing up via timemachine and adding a Solid State Drive. Boot times are amazing.

Comment: only one user and the system does have SSD installed. After the slow login it runs quite fast.